# How to add "credentials: include" to d3.json method? D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use the d3.json method to access JSON Data from an endpoint. I am able to successfully access the data using the fetch method below, however I am not sure how to change this to the d3.json method. How can I pass the argument "credentials:include"

```
fetch('http://0.0.0.0:example.com',{
     credentials: 'include'
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then( json => console.log(json))
```

My attempt would be something like this, however I am not sure where I would add the credentials argument.

```
d3.json('http://0.0.0.0:example.com', json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: d3 v5 uses fetch api, so you can do same with d3 api i guess

Comment: d3.json('http://0.0.0.0:example.com',{credentials: 'include'}).then(json => console.log(json))

Answer (score 0):

d3.json use fetch so the same will work

From the doc:

[d3.json](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json):
Fetches the JSON file at the specified input URL. If init is specified, it is passed along to the underlying call to fetch; see [RequestInit](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requestinit) for allowed fields.

```
d3.json('http://0.0.0.0:example.com', {credentials: "include"}, function(error, json) {
   console.log(json);
})
```

Comment: For me this results in the error: Uncaught Error: invalid callback:

Comment: You could try to catch an error to have an idea what is going wrong in the Promise

Comment: I am still getting the same error, but thanks for the help

Comment: It seems d3.json is using callback, not Promise. What version are you using? See my edit

Comment: I am using d3.v4